# How do you reference the executing assembly in DNX Core 5.0 (ASP.NET 5)?

Tags: c#, .net-assembly, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, dnx

I am porting some code from .NET 3.5 - 4.5. Inside of my assembly, I have some code that reads the resource from the currently executing assembly. However, `GetExecutingAssembly()` isn't a method on the `Assembly` type in DNX core 5.0.

```
var xsdStream = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetManifestResourceStream(xsdPath);
```

What is the equivalent of `Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly()` in DNX core 5.0? Or if I need a namespace to get that method back (an extension method perhaps?), what is the namespace?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

`typeof(<a type in that assembly>).GetTypeInfo().Assembly`

Comment: Can you use the approach from an assembly that is referenced by executing project? (Problem of cycling dependencies)

Comment: You can if you load a type by name

Comment: Thanks so much. If anyone googles for this relating to nlog...

`LogManager.AddHiddenAssembly(Assembly.Load(typeof(LogProvider)));`

becomes

`LogManager.AddHiddenAssembly(typeof(LogProvider).GetTypeInfo().Assembly)`