# Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly() available in .NET Core?

Tags: asp.net-core

Need to embed a json file as a source for testing in my .NET Core application. The author of this post http://codeopinion.com/asp-net-core-embedded-resource/  provided sample code that included the use of `var assembly = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();`However when I try this I get the error: `Cannot resolve symbol ‘GetExecutingAssembly’ and ‘Assembly’ does not contain a definition for ‘GetExecuringAssembly’`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you reference the executing assembly in DNX Core 5.0 (ASP.NET 5)?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32856659/how-do-you-reference-the-executing-assembly-in-dnx-core-5-0-asp-net-5)

Answer (score 36):

If you are targeting .NET Standard 1.5 or above, you may call any of the following:

```
System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
System.Reflection.Assembly.GetEntryAssembly();
System.Reflection.Assembly.GetCallingAssembly();
```

If targeting earlier versions of .NET Standard then the `typeof(SomeClass).GetTypeInfo().Assembly` method is the only way.

Comment: @jgauffin `System.Reflection.Assembly.GetEntryAssembly()` is part of .NET Core. There are tests for it in `corefx`: https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/6317e53b89680d83747d789c354bb1acda011758/src/System.Reflection/tests/AssemblyTests.cs#L120-L128

Comment: @jgauffin dotnetcore is part of .NET standard.

Answer (score 27):

There is no "static" `Assembly` class in .NET Standard prior to version `1.5`. Instead you have to do something like:

```
typeof(<AClassHere>).GetTypeInfo().Assembly
```

Where `<AClassHere>` should be replaced by the name of a class/type in the assembly you wish to load.

Comment: this is the best way I also know. but it is ugly :(

Answer (score 4):

Nope, it's not available in .NET Core 1.0/1.1.

However, if I remember correctly it will be back in [.NET Core 2.0](http://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2016/09/26/introducing-net-standard/) and the `netstandard2.0` which is to be released later this year, which will have a much bigger API surface and increased compatibility with libraries written against .NET >= 4.5 making it easier to port these to .NETStandard 2.0/2.1.

But many of the APIs implementations will be platform dependent. Means, you will be able to call `SomeAPI.GetSomething()` everywhere, but if run on .NET Core it may throw a `PlatformNotSupportedException`.

But most APIs about assembly scanning and discovering should be back in .NET Core/Standard 2.0. Stuff around `AppDomain` will still be missing as there are no AppDomains in .NET Core and processes should be used for isolation.

Comment: In addition to this, check out [this link for the alternative.](https://forums.asp.net/t/2001385.aspx?Assembly+GetExecutingAssembly+core)